# Unique key constraint without order of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table 
drug_interaction(drug1_id ,drug2_id )

I want to know if it is possible to have unique pairs of drug1_id and drug2_id without taking into consideration the order of the values. For example if (1,2) already exists in the table
then inserting (2,1) should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to do in MySQL.  In many databases, you can ensure that the drugs are in order using a `check` constraint:

```
check (drug1_id < drug2_Id)
```

However, MySQL does not actually enforce these constraints.

The only way you can enforce this is using a trigger on the table.

Comment: Actually, MySQL 8+ should enforce your constraint.

Comment: In my understanding, the question is more about how to guarantee uniqness of tuples (combinations included) than ordering (while enforcing ordering is sure a solution for it).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create two computed columns that store the smallest and greatest `drug_id`s on each record, and the put a unique constraint on them.

Consider:

```
create table drug_interaction(
    drug1_id int ,
    drug2_id int,
    drug_least    int as (least(drug1_id, drug2_id))    stored,
    drug_greatest int as (greatest(drug1_id, drug2_id)) stored,
    unique key unique_drugs (drug_least, drug_greatest)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9702eb10376f9bed438924d5b6e245d5)**:

```
insert into drug_interaction(drug1_id, drug2_id) values(1, 2)
-- ok

insert into drug_interaction(drug1_id, drug2_id) values(2, 1)
-- error: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'unique_drugs'
```